# Using OpenCV with Unity on Android

Tags: android, c++, opencv, unity-game-engine

I have a problem about using OpenCV with Unity on Android. I use OpenCV library native c++ plugin (.so file) I want to detect Rubik's cube and cube's color.

So I pass data from Unity's webcamtexture to OpenCV. It's good working when webcamtexture's width and height is small (320x240). But it has trouble when webcamtexture's width and height is big (480x640). And when webcamtexture's resolution set full screen (in this case I set 800x1280), app stops.

I tried to debug. It stop when I copy the data from OpenCV to Unity through using Marshal.Copy function. How can I solve this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpi7q.jpg)

(Its resolution is 320x240)

[Case1 (resolution is 320x240)]

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;

public class Controller : MonoBehaviour {
    public float RotateSpeed = 0.5f;

    public RawImage InImage;
    public RawImage OutImage;

    WebCamTexture wct;
    Texture2D outTexture;

    void Awake()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        int width = 1280;
        int height = 720;
#else
        int width = 320;
        int height = 240;
#endif

        NativeLibAdapter.InitCV(width, height);

        outTexture = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);

        wct = new WebCamTexture(width, height);
        wct.Play();
        // Ignore it.
        Debug.LogWarning("Foo Value in C++ is " + NativeLibAdapter.FooTest());
    }

    void Update()
    {

        if (wct.width > 100 && wct.height > 100)
        {
            Color32[] pixels = wct.GetPixels32();
            GCHandle pixelHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(pixels, GCHandleType.Pinned);

            IntPtr results = NativeLibAdapter.SubmitFrame(wct.width, wct.height, pixelHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
            int bufferSize = wct.width * wct.height * 4;
            byte[] rawData = new byte[bufferSize];

            if (results != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.Copy(results, rawData, 0, bufferSize);

                outTexture.LoadRawTextureData(rawData);
                outTexture.Apply();
            }

            OutImage.texture = outTexture;

            rawData = null;
            pixelHandle.Free();
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVwf5.jpg)
(Its resolution is 480x640. There are many noise.)

[Case2 (resolution is 480x640)]

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;

public class Controller : MonoBehaviour {
    public float RotateSpeed = 0.5f;

    public RawImage InImage;
    public RawImage OutImage;

    WebCamTexture wct;
    Texture2D outTexture;

    void Awake()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        int width = 1280;
        int height = 720;
#else
        int width = 480;
        int height = 640;
#endif

        NativeLibAdapter.InitCV(width, height);

        outTexture = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);

        wct = new WebCamTexture(width, height);
        wct.Play();
        // Ignore it.
        Debug.LogWarning("Foo Value in C++ is " + NativeLibAdapter.FooTest());
    }

    void Update()
    {

        if (wct.width > 100 && wct.height > 100)
        {
            Color32[] pixels = wct.GetPixels32();
            GCHandle pixelHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(pixels, GCHandleType.Pinned);

            IntPtr results = NativeLibAdapter.SubmitFrame(wct.width, wct.height, pixelHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
            int bufferSize = wct.width * wct.height * 4;
            byte[] rawData = new byte[bufferSize];

            if (results != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.Copy(results, rawData, 0, bufferSize);

                outTexture.LoadRawTextureData(rawData);
                outTexture.Apply();
            }

            OutImage.texture = outTexture;

            rawData = null;
            pixelHandle.Free();
        }
    }
}
```

It just change width and height variable.

[Case 3 (resolution is full screen on device)]

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;

public class Controller : MonoBehaviour {
    public float RotateSpeed = 0.5f;

    public RawImage InImage;
    public RawImage OutImage;

    WebCamTexture wct;
    Texture2D outTexture;

    void Awake()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        int width = 1280;
        int height = 720;
#else
        int width = 480;
        int height = 640;
#endif

        NativeLibAdapter.InitCV(Screen.width, Screen.height);

        outTexture = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);

        wct = new WebCamTexture(Screen.width, Screen.height);
        wct.Play();

        // Ignore it.
        Debug.LogWarning("Foo Value in C++ is " + NativeLibAdapter.FooTest());
    }

    void Update()
    {

        if (wct.width > 100 && wct.height > 100)
        {
            Color32[] pixels = wct.GetPixels32();
            GCHandle pixelHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(pixels, GCHandleType.Pinned);

            IntPtr results = NativeLibAdapter.SubmitFrame(wct.width, wct.height, pixelHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
            int bufferSize = wct.width * wct.height * 4;
            byte[] rawData = new byte[bufferSize];

            if (results != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                // here! App stops. I don't know why App stops.
                Marshal.Copy(results, rawData, 0, bufferSize);

                outTexture.LoadRawTextureData(rawData);
                outTexture.Apply();
            }

            OutImage.texture = outTexture;

            rawData = null;
            pixelHandle.Free();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using:

- IDE
- Unity 2018.1.19f
- Android Studio 3.4.2
- OpenCV 3.4.3

Answer (score 0):

You have the following code initializing your CV buffer:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        int width = 1280;
        int height = 720;
#else
        int width = 480;
        int height = 640;
#endif

        NativeLibAdapter.InitCV(Screen.width, Screen.height);
```

Your initialization of the CV buffer is not enough to handle 800x1280, so you are likely running out of memory. It is expected that performance will dip as your size increases, as memory consumption is greater (640x480 is 4 times more data than 320x240, and therefore much more garbage collection and data processing each frame). You will need to increase your width and height to encompass the maximum resolution, or limit the pixels you retrieve from GetPixels() before feeding the data into CV.